using vanna ai but can't connect to my database
I was trying to use vanna ai in my notebook.The code are as follow:
!pip install vanna
import vanna as vn
from vanna.remote import VannaDefault
vn = VannaDefault(model='', api_key='')
vn.connect_to_mysql(
    host='localhost',
    dbname='',
    user='root',
    password='',
    port=3306
)

and when I run the vn.connect_to_mysql(...),the error occur:
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:649, in Connection.connect(self, sock)
    648 try:
--> 649     sock = socket.create_connection(
    650         (self.host, self.port), self.connect_timeout, **kwargs
    651     )
    652     break

File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310/lib/python3.11/socket.py:851, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, all_errors)
    850 if not all_errors:
--> 851     raise exceptions[0]
    852 raise ExceptionGroup("create_connection failed", exceptions)

File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310/lib/python3.11/socket.py:836, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, all_errors)
    835     sock.bind(source_address)
--> 836 sock.connect(sa)
    837 # Break explicitly a reference cycle

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vanna/base/base.py:982, in VannaBase.connect_to_mysql(self, host, dbname, user, password, port)
    981 try:
--> 982     conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
    983                            user=user,
    984                            password=password,
    985                            database=dbname,
    986                            port=port,
    987                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    988 except pymysql.Error as e:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:361, in Connection.__init__(self, user, password, host, database, unix_socket, port, charset, collation, sql_mode, read_default_file, conv, use_unicode, client_flag, cursorclass, init_command, connect_timeout, read_default_group, autocommit, local_infile, max_allowed_packet, defer_connect, auth_plugin_map, read_timeout, write_timeout, bind_address, binary_prefix, program_name, server_public_key, ssl, ssl_ca, ssl_cert, ssl_disabled, ssl_key, ssl_key_password, ssl_verify_cert, ssl_verify_identity, compress, named_pipe, passwd, db)
    360 else:
--> 361     self.connect()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:716, in Connection.connect(self, sock)
    715         print(exc.traceback)
--> 716     raise exc
    718 # If e is neither DatabaseError or IOError, It's a bug.
    719 # But raising AssertionError hides original error.
    720 # So just reraise it.

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[96], line 1
----> 1 vn.connect_to_mysql(
      2     host='localhost',
      3     dbname='',
      4     user='root',
      5     password='',
      6     port=3306
      7 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/vanna/base/base.py:989, in VannaBase.connect_to_mysql(self, host, dbname, user, password, port)
    982     conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
    983                            user=user,
    984                            password=password,
    985                            database=dbname,
    986                            port=port,
    987                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    988 except pymysql.Error as e:
--> 989     raise ValidationError(e)
    991 def run_sql_mysql(sql: str) -> Union[pd.DataFrame, None]:
    992     if conn:

ValidationError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

ps:I remove some personal imformation (password ,db_name) above.
after this error occur I check the two potential problem and the results are as followed:
C:\Users\Administrator>sc query MySQL80
SERVICE_NAME: MySQL80
TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
STATE              : 4  RUNNING
(STOPPABLE, PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -an | findstr 3306
TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:33060          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    [::]:33060             [::]:0                 LISTENING
I am really confused right now.
